# How to get URL at the time Google analytics event was fired?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track various events on my website. I am defining Category, Action, and Label for each event. How do I track from which page/URL the event got triggered.

One way is to put page name in Category OR put URL in the label? Is there any easy way of this OR does google save URL along with each event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics automatically associates each event with a URL.  It uses the terminology "Page".

There is a report at **Behavior** →  **Events** → **Pages**.  It lists the pages that have the most events.  From there you can click to see which events happen on that page.

You could also add "Page" as a second dimension to other event reports.  That would let you see on which pages your top events happen. [image]